# A C++ JSON library which accepts inputs with comments and multiline strings

Tags: library, c++, json

I'm developing a program written in C++ for editing Minecraft datapacks. These datapacks can contain JSON files. Minecraft can parse JSON files with comments and strings spanning multiple lines.
For example:

- JSON with comments:

```
{
    // This is a comment
    "key": "value"
}
```

- JSON with multiline strings:

```
{
    "key": "val
ue"
}
```

I want to mimic Minecraft behaviours although the JSON standard does not allow both of these "features". After searching, I found some libraries which support comments, but none of them support multiline strings. Is there any C++ JSON library that allows JSON with comments and multiline strings?